# Azure Active Directory Single Sign On

Tags: azure, active-directory, yaf, mojoportal, azure-active-directory

I have a few websites that are running mojoPortal and Yet Another Forum, and several custom websites with ASP.net web forms (vb.net).  I plan to add additional ASP.net websites too.  I would like to have a single sign on for all sites, be able to setup groups and roles per site, and store the user's full name, phone, email, and other custom fields.

Each website currently has its own ASP.net membership database.  There are about 1000 total users.  It would be nice to be able to import the current members into Azure AD, but it will be OK if each user has to create a new login account.  I've never used active directory but it sounds like Azure AD will do what I want.  I plan to move all websites to an Azure virtual machine.

Before I start testing, I want to find out if single sign on will work with various ASP.net websites, and how complicated the setup and configuration will be.  Can I import users to AD?  I guess if a website supports AD or LDAP, then AZure AD will work?  I'm hoping it will be as easy as adding the AD connection string in web.config?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It probably wont be as easy as adding the connection string. The Ad SSO service needs to be implemented using WIF (Windows Identity Framework) in your application. If you are already using WIF then it could be that simple. If not then you will need to implement WIF.

See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/07/12/announcing-the-developer-preview-of-windows-azure-active-directory.aspx) to help you get a better understanding of what is involved.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/07/12/announcing-the-developer-preview-of-windows-azure-active-directory.aspx